# History API (Dive Into HTML 5 / CH. 11)

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, single-page-application, browser-history

I am trying to wrap my head around the history API. I am reading this along with this: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html. It is relevant to me because, I am creating a single-page-application. There are two areas of the chapter's code that I don't understand:

```
function addClicker(link) {

    ....

    swapPhoto(link.href);
    history.pushState(null, null, link.href);

    ....

}
```

In the above code - what is `link.href`? I think I understand that the `href` is referring to the link attribute, and the `link` is being passed to the `addClicker` method. Is this just the way in which you have to refer to the `href` attribute of the `link` that is being passed in?

Secondly:

```
function swapPhoto(href) {

    ....

    req.open("GET","http://diveintohtml5.info/examples/history/gallery/" + href.split("/").pop(), false);

    ....

}
```

What is happening with the above line? I've been trying to figure out what the `open()` function does with that second parameter...

I am trying to make it so that when a user logs in through a login form (and submit button) - the profile page gets brought up (I am making an `SPA`) - and then the user could go back to the main page configuration after logging in. So I think I am trying to do something like:

```
 addClicker(document.getElementById("[SUBMIT BUTTON]"));
```

However, the submit button doesn't have a `href` attribute...so I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: i don't think submit is compat with pushState in raw form, but you can target a hidden iframe and sync up the submit event with a render command.

Comment: @dandavis thanks...how would i do this? can you point me to any examples?

Comment: i'm not sure what you're trying to do. you say you have one page, but then say you want to pull up a "profile page" via submit, neither of which makes much sense in a SPA... If you don't need to undo the form submit, it's valid just let it submit as normal; you don't need to re-wire everything everything, just the bookmarkable sections of user interaction.

Comment: @dandavis the "profile page" is just a template that gets loaded into the SPA - I was exploring the history api as a solution to the SPA history problem, and naturally - the first place I thought to add the functionality was after the user logged in (as this is the first interaction the user has with the site that will require a "back" function).

Comment: @dandavis found this - https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax    might be what i am looking for? if u see the part about `.pjax.submit`

Comment: @dandavis although...it seems this function is only good for loading something into a div on submit...not creating a history